# Meteor: App resets form inputs if used with slow hard disk on server

Tags: mongodb, meteor, hard-drive

If the form inputs change, the client updates the document, and the changed document is written to MongoDB subsequently. No further submit or save is required to save the document, which is the desired behavior.

If the server hard disk is fast enough, this works as expected. But if the hard disk blocks for few seconds, the input fields are reset and the typed letters are lost. Now I would like to understand and solve this problem, because it should never ever happen -- not even once a week -- that typed letters get lost (except for a browser or server crash).

What do I need to change?

I send each key press. Should I buffer several key presses and send them in a chunk? Does a built-in buffering solution exist in Meteor?

Does the hard disk's block exceed a timeout in MongoDB or Meteor and discard changes? Where can I find the timeout and change it?

What else could be the reason?

Comment: You probably want to wrap your mongo writes in a `throttle` command. See http://underscorejs.org/#throttle. A value between 250-500 ms would be ideal. Underscore is built into Meteor by default.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this you can store reactive form data in MiniMongo on the client only and keep a Session variable with the _id of the document you are working with. Decide when you should save to the server based on your app requirements and at that point call a method to update the server collection with your client's minimongo data. With this model your client's collection is all in memory.

So on the client your update event would look like this:

```
'keyup input#myinput':function(e){
var modifier = {$set: {'mydata': e.currentTarget.value}};
LocalCollection.update({Session.get('documentId')},modifier);
}
```

and your save event would look like this:

```
'click btn#save':function(e){
var id= Session.get('documentId');
ServerCollection.upsert({_id: id,LocalCollection.findOne(id)});
}
```

You can expand on that to setup a save timer, or save based on a number of edits. When and how you save to the server is up to you but if you have tons of rapid changes just keep it in client memory until you are ready to commit a chunk of new data.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I gonna give it a try to see if it solves my problem. In addition, I guess I would like to find a way to test if a save was successful in order to adapt to server health: If the server can do fast writes, I send writes every 100 ms. If it is on overload, I write once a period of 5 seconds. Question is: How can I know if the server is currently slow or not?

Comment: I like your solution ! To remove the need to use a button, which is what the OP states, I'd suggest changing `click btn#save` to `blur input#myinput`.

Comment: @user1625837 you can set var updates = ServerCollection.upsert() and it will return to you the number of records the server has updated. I think you can simply look at how long it takes from calling the upsert until you receive your response. Now you have an idea of how long it took to write that number of records. However, I don't know the internals of upsert and if it runs async or not so this may not be a good benchmark.

Comment: I tried it using a timeout, but even if I save no more frequently than once a half second, the input is still reset. I am using the `save` method of an Angular-Meteor's `$meteorObject`: http://angular-meteor.com/api/meteorObject . The promise returned by `save` always calls the success function, never the error function. It seems to pretend successful saves, though they fail.